# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object when logging in twice

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Not sure what's happening here.

If have this as my login function in one of my controllers

```
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();
}

public function postLogin()
{
    if( Auth::attempt([
        'username'=>Input::get('username'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
    ]))
    {
        return $this->user->username;
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

and this as my logout

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return Redirect::to('login');
}
```

If I sign in once then it displays the username , just like I want.
If I logout and log in again, the I get a

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Then if I logout and re-login it works once more until I logout again.
Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is both in:

```
$this->user = Auth::user();
```

and

```
return $this->user->username;
```

In constructor you should rather do something like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
   $this->user = Auth::user();
}
```

but when logging in you shouldn't use:

```
return $this->user->username;
```

but

```
return Auth::user()->username;
```